# Visual2013 error when trying to update data to SQL (System.InvalidOperationException)

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrJDl.png)
Everytime im trying to update data i get this:

> Unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
> WindowsApplication2.exe
>  Additional information: Update requires a
> valid UpdateCommand when passing a DataRow collection with changed row

I even recreated table and form in MS visual and nothing happened

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: SQL server 2014 managment studio

Comment: btw as you can see i have a lot of forms and i wrote code like that, i have almost the same tables at all but only inside this table i have this error

Comment: People do not click on images here - please present your code in textual form.

Comment: Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.PracivnikiBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.My_databaseDataSet)
    End Sub
End Class